# Checking if a string has balanced parentheses

Tags: ruby

I am currently working on a Ruby Problem quiz but I'm not sure if my solution is right. After running the check, it shows that the compilation was successful but i'm just worried it is not the right answer.

The problem:

> A string S consisting only of characters '(' and ')' is called properly nested if:
>
> - S is empty,
> - S has the form "(U)" where
>     U is a properly nested string,
> - S has
>     the form "VW" where V and W are
>     properly nested strings.
>
> For example, "(()(())())" is properly nested and "())" isn't.
>
> Write a function
>
> ```
> def nesting(s)
> ```
>
> that given a string S returns 1 if S
>   is properly nested and 0 otherwise.
>   Assume that the length of S does not
>   exceed 1,000,000. Assume that S
>   consists only of characters '(' and
>   ')'.
>
> For example, given S = "(()(())())"
>   the function should return 1 and given
>   S = "())" the function should return
>   0, as explained above.

Solution:

```
def nesting ( s )
    # write your code here

    if s == '(()(())())' && s.length <= 1000000
        return 1
    elsif s == ' ' && s.length <= 1000000
        return 1
    elsif 
        s == '())'
        return 0
    end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't really have much to do with math, so I removed the tag.

Comment: I can imagine you tried to do a recursive definition, but it is not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are descriptions of two algorithms that should accomplish the goal. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to turn them into code (unless you explicitly ask for a code solution):

1. Start with a variable set to `0` and loop through each character in the string: when you see a '(', add one to the variable; when you see a ')', subtract one from the variable. If the variable ever goes negative, you have seen too many ')' and can return `0` immediately. If you finish looping through the characters and the variable is not exactly `0`, then you had too many '(' and should return `0`.
2. Remove every occurrence of '()' in the string (replace with ''). Keep doing this until you find that nothing has been replaced (check the return value of `gsub!`). If the string is empty, the parentheses were matched. If the string is not empty, it was mismatched.

Comment: Addition for #2, first remove all characters that are not `(` or `)`.

Comment: @gnur: The problem description doesn't appear to allow for any other characters in the string.

Comment: @RHSeeger Ah, I see, I misread. I thought it said it only consists of characters and `(` and `)`.

Comment: still great algorithm

Answer (score 4):

You're not supposed to just enumerate the given examples. You're supposed to solve the problem generally. You're also not supposed to check that the length is below 1000000, you're allowed to assume that.

The most straight forward solution to this problem is to iterate through the string and keep track of how many parentheses are open right now. If you ever see a closing parenthesis when no parentheses are currently open, the string is not well-balanced. If any parentheses are still open when you reach the end, the string is not well-balanced. Otherwise it is.

Alternatively you could also turn the specification directly into a regex pattern using the recursive regex feature of ruby 1.9 if you were so inclined.

Comment: For the regex route, check http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ruby3_extract_regular_expressions.pdf

Answer (score 4):

My algorithm would use stacks for this purpose. Stacks are meant for solving such problems

### Algorithm

1. Define a hash which holds the list of balanced brackets for
   instance {"(" => ")", "{" => "}", and so on...}
2. Declare a stack (in our case, array) i.e. brackets = []
3. Loop through the string using each_char and compare each character with keys of the hash and push it to the brackets
4. Within the same loop compare it with the values of the hash and pop the character from brackets
5. In the end, if the brackets stack is empty, the brackets are balanced.

   `def brackets_balanced?(string) 
       return false if string.length < 2
       brackets_hash = {"(" => ")", "{" => "}", "[" => "]"}
       brackets = []
       string.each_char do |x|
         brackets.push(x) if brackets_hash.keys.include?(x)
         brackets.pop if brackets_hash.values.include?(x)
       end
       return brackets.empty?
     end`

Comment: This will give incorrect result if *string* equals `')()'`. The first parenthese will pop an empty array, leaving brackets unchanged, and the subsequent parentheses will pass the test.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem theoretically. By using a grammar like this:

```
S ← LSR | LR
L ← (
R ← )
```

The grammar should be easily solvable by recursive algorithm.
That would be the most elegant solution. Otherwise as already mentioned here count the open parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a neat way to do it using inject:

```
class String
  def valid_parentheses?
    valid = true
    self.gsub(/[^\(\)]/, '').split('').inject(0) do |counter, parenthesis|
      counter += (parenthesis == '(' ? 1 : -1)
      valid = false if counter < 0
      counter
    end.zero? && valid
  end
end

> "(a+b)".valid_parentheses?    # => true
> "(a+b)(".valid_parentheses?   # => false
> "(a+b))".valid_parentheses?   # => false
> "(a+b))(".valid_parentheses?  # => false
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right to be worried; I think you've got the very wrong end of the stick, and you're solving the problem too literally (the info that the string doesn't exceed 1,000,000 characters is just to stop people worrying about how slow their code would run if the length was 100times that, and the examples are just that - examples - not the definitive list of strings you can expect to receive)

I'm not going to do your homework for you (by writing the code), but will give you a pointer to a solution that occurs to me:

The string is correctly nested if every left bracket has a right-bracket to the right of it, or a correctly nested set of brackets between them. So how about a recursive function, or a loop, that removes the string matches "()". When you run out of matches, what are you left with? Nothing? That was a properly nested string then. Something else (like ')' or ')(', etc) would mean it was not correctly nested in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Define method:

```
def check_nesting str
  pattern = /\(\)/
  while str =~ pattern do
    str = str.gsub pattern, ''
  end

  str.length == 0
end
```

And test it:

```
>ruby nest.rb (()(())())
true

>ruby nest.rb (()
false

>ruby nest.rb ((((()))))
true

>ruby nest.rb (()
false

>ruby nest.rb (()(((())))())
true

>ruby nest.rb (()(((())))()
false
```

Comment: Note that this can be done far more tersely by a) Using a string literal instead of a regex and b) checking the return value of `gsub!` (perhaps with a `dup` beforehand to preserve the original)

Comment: @Yar, no I dont :) The only thing that is not handled in my code is checking for empty string at beginning of check_nesting. But this is just one line of code: if str.empty? return true

Comment: @Yar, read the question: A string S consisting only of characters '(' and ')'... Any questions?

Comment: No questions and +1 (already upvoted when I left the first comment).

Comment: @Yar, thanks. Besides, the regex for your type of quiz with letters in prev comment can be pattern = /\([^(^)]*\)/

Comment: @Hck what would the recursive regex look like? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution only returns the correct answer for the strings "(()(())())" and "())". You surely need a solution that works for any string!

As a start, how about counting the number of occurrences of `(` and `)`, and seeing if they are equal?

Comment: ')))(((' would pass the count test, but is not valid according the spec

Comment: Well of course, that's why I said 'as a start'! I didn't want to give the game away completely!